# How to split an array from an array from a desired part when have 1 to many relationship working on codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, split

I have this data coming from a from where `gropup_id` is a dropdown with multiple 
selection what I want is to insert values in the data table but not `gropup_id` I want to extract it a separate array and insert it into another table later.

```
    array(11) {
  ["full_name"]=>
  string(5) "gjiut"
  ["username"]=>
  string(3) "hhj"
  ["password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["confirm_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["email"]=>
  string(26) "eshopdesigners11@gmail.com"
  ["company_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["mobile"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["skype_id"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["role_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["gropup_id"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

My table relation ship

user table

```
id 
user_name
```

group table

```
id
group_name
```

user_group_table

```
user_id
group_id
```

I tried this but not working

```
$post = $this->input->post();

$postArray = $post;
$secondaryarray = array();

foreach ($postArray as $key => $value) {

    if (strpos($value, "gropup_id") != FALSE)
        $secondaryarray[] = $value;

    unset($post[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gropup_id is a key, not a value in the postArray.

Instead of

```
if (strpos($value, "gropup_id") != FALSE)
```

do

```
if ( $key == "gropup_id" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Improverd code which works perfect

```
$post = $this->input->post();


        $postArray = $post;
        $secondaryarray = array();

        foreach ($postArray as $key => $value) {

            if ($key == "gropup_id")
                $secondaryarray = $value;

            unset($postArray['gropup_id']);
        }
```